# My Mac Pro body is too hot

Tags: macos, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro (Not Macbook Pro). It was working so good but recently when I touch its body it is too hot.

I checked the RAM, CPU and memory usage. all of them are below 70% so I can not find the root cause of the heating.

Does someone know how can I find its root cause?

Comment: the trashcan model or the cheesegrater model? What year/specification?

Comment: It is Mac Pro (Late 2013) and the model identifier is MacPro6,1

Comment: Clean dust out of it?

Comment: Yes, I do it yesterday

Comment: Try something like [smcFanControl](https://www.eidac.de) (free, basic) or better in this instance, [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) ($18 with 14 day trial, comprehensive) to see if you can at least track down what's getting hot.

Comment: I just installed that, now it shows 55 degree(C). 'PSU Secondary heatsink' and 'PCIe Switch Diode' are most hot parts.

Comment: I can't compare numbers, unfortunately - I'm on a cheesegrater so the component names don't match. If iStat marks anything in red, then that's one to look at. Without knowing that specific component or its nominal running temp, I'd say 55 would normally be nothing to worry about. My CPUA is hitting 65 right now & that's my hottest component, & still in the black.

Answer (score 0):

If a computer is overheating it's likely to be a fan malfunction or the normal airflow being blocked for some reason, for instance if you installed third party components that it wasn't designed for, or installed components in different places than expected, that could be another reason.